# Fatou's lemma extension and dropping lim inf.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a sequence of elements in $M(X,S)$, let $g\in M^+(X,S)$ such that $\int gd\mu<\infty$ and $f_n\ge-g\ $ $(a.e.- \mu)\ \forall n\in \Bbb N\ $ in $E\in S$. Then, it follows from Fatou's lemma that:

$$\int_{E} \liminf_{n\to \infty} (f_n)d\mu\le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_E f_nd\mu$$
**Question 1** Can someone please give me a reference for the above generalised fatou's lemma.

**Question 2** What is the condition on $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ so that we may drop $\lim \inf$ and we have $$\int_{E} \lim_{n\to \infty} (f_n)d\mu\le \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f_nd\mu$$
My try: Define $$h_n=f_n+g$$ Then $h_n\geq 0$.
Applying fatou's lemma to $h_n$ we have $$\int_{E} \liminf_{n\to \infty} (h_n)d\mu\le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_E h_nd\mu$$
So we get $$\int_{E} \liminf_{n\to \infty} (f_n+g)d\mu\le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_E (f_n+g)d\mu$$
How do we conclude?

Comment: I don't have the book on me to confirm, but this should probably be in *Real Analysis* by Royden and Fitzpatrick?

Comment: @Zim So both of my questions are answered there? Can you please give a brief idea for the proof.

Comment: This is just Fatou's Lemma applied to $f_n+g$. Nobody would state this separetely as a theorem.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy So the condition that $g>0$ is needed or not?

Comment: No. It is not needed.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy So we get $$\int_{E} \liminf_{n\to \infty} (f_n+g)d\mu\le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_E (f_n+g)d\mu$$
How do we conclude?

Comment: $\lim \inf (a_n+b)=\lim \inf a_n +b$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you so much. Please answer my question 2 in the post. In what condition can we write $\lim$ in place of $\lim \inf$ in the inequality?

Comment: The limit on both sides have to exist. That is it. No extra condition is needed.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Then why sir we have $g>0$ given in every "Extension of Fatou's lemma"?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy So if $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ exist and the integral  $\int_{E} \lim_{n\to \infty} (f_n)d\mu$  is finite and also      
$   \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f_nd\mu$ is finite then we will have the following:         $$\int_{E} \lim_{n\to \infty} (f_n)d\mu\le \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f_nd\mu$$  Is this true?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Please reply Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_n(x)=\inf\{f_i(x) : i \geq n \}$.  Then $g_n(x)$ increases monotonically to $\liminf f_n$ and by the monotone convergence theorem, $\int g_n = \int \liminf f_n$.  Since $g_n \leq f_n$ for every $n$, we have $\int g_n \leq \int f_n$.  Your result then follows.